# Wrapped Caption on Arranged Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, caption, annotate, superscript

I am trying to put 4 plots together and add a long caption (Figure caption) underneath of the plots. However, when I try to add the caption, it puts the wrapped caption over top of the graphs. Additionally, there is a part of my caption that needs to be superscripted in the middle, but the caption won't allow for the superscript.

The following code is what I have been trying.

```
caption<-"Long arbitrary caption with word^superscripted in the middle. "

annotate_figure((ggarrange(HR1Plot,HR3Plot,HR12Plot,HR24Plot,
      ncol=2,nrow=2,
      labels=c("A","B","C","D"))),
      fig.lab = caption,
      fig.lab.pos = "bottom.left"
      )
```

The caption is now over the entire graph instead of under the graphs. I'm also asking for help on how to superscript the word in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

One option to fix your issue would be to switch to the `patchwork` package to glue your plots together and which allows to add a title, caption, ... the same way as we would do for a single `ggplot`. Second, to fix your issue with the superscript you could create your caption as a `?plotmath` expression.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

HR1Plot <- HR3Plot <- HR12Plot <- HR24Plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

caption <- expression(
  Long ~ arbitrary ~ caption ~ with ~
  word^{superscripted} ~ "in" ~ the ~ middle.
)

list(HR1Plot, HR3Plot, HR12Plot, HR24Plot) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) &
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A", caption = caption) &
  theme(
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** First, `wrap_plots` requires the `patchwork` package which you have to install and attach as I do. Second, `plotmath` could be a bit tricky, i.e. you have to wrap the `,` in quotes, i.e. use `","`. Also besides the `~` separattor which adds a space there is also a `*` separator.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

HR1Plot <- HR3Plot <- HR12Plot <- HR24Plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

caption <- expression(
  th~or~without~forskolin~on~S16~cell~viability.~
    Using~the~CyQUANT^TM~MTT~Cell~Viability~Assay~Kit~(Thermo~Fisher)*","
  ~the~immortalized~rat~S16~cell~line~(ATCC~CRL-2941)~was~treated~with~0*","~0.1,
)

list(HR1Plot, HR3Plot, HR12Plot, HR24Plot) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) &
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A", caption = caption) &
  theme(
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

However, while `plotmath` is the way to go for math expression, in your case I would suggest to switch to e.g. `ggtext` to add your superscript text. The latter allows to add use some basic HTML, CSS or markdown to format text, e.g. you could add a superscript via a `<sup>` tag. Additionally, as you caption is quite long `ggtext` makes it easy to split your caption over mutliple lines (which `plotmath` does not) and via `ggtext::elment_textbox_simple` you could achieve that more or less automatically:

```r
library(ggtext)

caption <- "
  th or without forskolin on S16 cell viability. 
    Using the CyQUANT<sup>TM</sup> MTT Cell Viability Assay Kit (Thermo Fisher)
   the immortalized rat S16 cell line (ATCC CRL-2941) was treated with 0, 0.1,
"

list(HR1Plot, HR3Plot, HR12Plot, HR24Plot) |>
  wrap_plots(ncol = 2) &
  plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A", caption = caption) &
  theme(
    plot.caption = ggtext::element_textbox_simple(hjust = 0),
    plot.tag = element_text(face = "bold")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I am attempting this and for the caption, I am getting the following error:
Error: unexpected '~' in "th~or~without~forskolin~on~S16~cell~viability.~Using~the~"CyQUANT^TM"~MTT~Cell~Viability~Assay~Kit~(Thermo~Fisher),~the~immortalized~rat~S16~cell~line~(ATCC~CRL-2941)~was~treated~with~0,~0.1,~"

I also get the following error when trying to do the list function: 
Error in wrap_plots(list(HR1Plot, HR3Plot, HR12Plot, HR24Plot), ncol = 2) : 
  could not find function "wrap_plots"

Comment: `plotmath` could be a bit tricky at the beginning. Instead I would suggest to switch to the `ggtext` package. See my edit.